# is possible to install oracle jdk 8 in jenkins docker container

Tags: java, docker, jenkins

I am build an app in jenkins docker container,but jenkins using openjdk default,and sometimes openjdk compile jar could not run,so I want to install Oracle JDK 8 in jenkins container,the docker using alpline.Is it possible to install Oracle JDK in apline?I am searching from internet and find less infomation.And some not working:https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Installing_Oracle_Java.Any suggestion?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/Docker-Hub-frolvlad/docker-alpine-java) may help you!

Comment: should I add it to my exists container,I aready have jenkins docker container and want to install docker into it.@ShekharRai

Comment: Tough haven't tested yet - but appending [Dockefile](https://github.com/Docker-Hub-frolvlad/docker-alpine-java/blob/master/Dockerfile)'s commands as much needed should do the trick.

Comment: In all likelihood, installing Oracle JDK for use in a non-Oracle commercial.use violates the new [license](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/oracle-jdk-faqs.html), read [FAQ](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/distribution.xml). [Primer](https://www.lakesidesoftware.com/blog/java-did-what-understanding-how-2019-java-licensing-changes-impact-you). I'd suggest an adoptopenjdk binary or openjdk package and work through the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to using this command in Dockerfile to dowload JDK and install:

```
 RUN wget -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz -O /tmp/jdk-8-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

if could not download from Oracle, replace the url to custom jdk download url(put jdk package into your own server).